# Loading complex nexted XML to hive table

Tags: sql, xml, hadoop, hive, xml-parsing

Is it possible to add a complex nested xml as shown below to hive table.

```
<items>
<item id="0001" type="donut">
<name>Cake</name>
<ppu>0.55</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
<batter id="1003">Blueberry</batter>
<batter id="1003">Devil's Food</batter>
</batters>
<topping id="5001">None</topping>
<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
<topping id="5007">Powdered Sugar</topping>
<topping id="5006">Chocolate with Sprinkles</topping>
<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
</item>
<item id="0002" type="donut">
<name>Raised</name>
<ppu>0.55</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
</batters>
<topping id="5001">None</topping>
<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
</item>
<item id="0003" type="donut">
<name>Buttermilk</name>
<ppu>0.55</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
<batter id="1002">Chocolate</batter>
</batters>
</item>
<item id="0004" type="bar">
<name>Bar</name>
<ppu>0.75</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
</batters>
<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
<fillings>
<filling id="7001">
<name>None</name>
<addcost>0</addcost>
</filling>
<filling id="7002">
<name>Custard</name>
<addcost>0.25</addcost>
</filling>
<filling id="7003">
<name>Whipped Cream</name>
<addcost>0.25</addcost>
</filling>
</fillings>
</item>
<item id="0005" type="twist">
<name>Twist</name>
<ppu>0.65</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
</batters>
<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
<topping id="5005">Sugar</topping>
</item>
<item id="0006" type="filled">
<name>Filled</name>
<ppu>0.75</ppu>
<batters>
<batter id="1001">Regular</batter>
</batters>
<topping id="5002">Glazed</topping>
<topping id="5007">Powdered Sugar</topping>
<topping id="5003">Chocolate</topping>
<topping id="5004">Maple</topping>
<fillings>
<filling id="7002">
<name>Custard</name>
<addcost>0</addcost>
</filling>
<filling id="7003">
<name>Whipped Cream</name>
<addcost>0</addcost>
</filling>
<filling id="7004">
<name>Strawberry Jelly</name>
<addcost>0</addcost>
</filling>
<filling id="7005">
<name>Rasberry Jelly</name>
<addcost>0</addcost>
</filling>
</fillings>
</item>
</items>
```

I had been able to map till 1001, 1002, 1003 but the values of the same,I am not able to extract.
I loaded the xml to hive table and extracted using xpath. I need to get the values regular, chocolate, blueberry.

I added the following into hive table (store.choclate) and query as

select xpath(str, '/items/item/batters/batter/@id') from store.chocolate

This gives the values 1001, 1002, 1003. How will write a query to extract regular, chocolate and bluebeery?

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid xml?

Comment: Yes it is and I loaded a similar kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

As in the query loaded the xml data as a single table and created view on top of it. The query had been structured as

```
select xpath(str, '/items/item/batters/batter[@id="1001"]/text()')
```

That will extract the value of 'Regular'. On similar ground it can be built for other fields